# Missing AllegroTTF-5.0.framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, cmake, allegro, allegro5

I have actually followed the guide http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=OSX,_Xcode_4,_Framework to install the allegro5 and AllegroTTF-5.0.framework  was missing and so i deleted everything and followed  http://stefanhendriks.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/getting-started-with-allegro-5-1-on-mac-os-x-10-8-xcode-4-5-and-homebrew/ this link and still the framework is missing i just don't know where i went wrong and os that i am using is a mac can anyone help !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial there is a step:

`brew install freetype`

did it work out for you as expected?

It should install the nescesary dependencies to make the TTF component of Allegro work.

If not, is there any error message you are seeing when you generate the `makefile` for Allegro with `cmake`?

Comment: hey i rectified the problem , just used free type 2.5.0.1 instead of 2.5.1 and it worked like a charm